# Facebook Android SDK not registering installs

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I created an app in Unity and published it to an Eclipse Android project, then I included the Facebook SDK in the project, I also followed the getting started wizard in the developer site.

I added the following line of code to the onResume() function of my main activity:

```
com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this, "MY FB APP ID");
```

In the Manifest file of the app I added the following:

```
<activity android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    </activity>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    </activity>
    <activity android:exported="true" android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDeepLinkingActivity">
    </activity>
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
```

I also added the FB app Id to the strings.xml file in res/values folder.

I generated a Hash Key (in windows) with the following command in command prompt:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Which generated a 28 character string, but I still did not see any app installs registered on Android.
So after searching more I found the following code on this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

```
    // Add code to print out the key hash
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

I changed the package name from "com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook" to the package name of my app, added it to the onCreate() function of the main activity, and ran the code, which logged a hash key. I copied the returned key into the app settings on the facebook developer site, but I am still not getting any installs or events registering on Android.

I also have an iOS version of the app and there everything is working perfectly.

I would really appreciate any suggestions/ideas/anything as to how to get the Facebook SDK to register installs and events on Android.

Comment: I don't think you need the key hash set up for just reporting app events. Have you tried this from multiple devices, or just a single device?

Comment: Just a single device. I am looking only to record the app events, if I remove the hash key will it work? or is there something else that I am missing?

Comment: You shouldn't need the key hash to report installs. In general, the install is only reported once per install (so subsequent app opens on the same device won't report it again). If you're not seeing anything, try to uninstall the app altogether, and then install/open it again, or try it on another device. Also, what version of the SDK are you using? Are you using the Android advertiser ID and/or have the Facebook app installed?

Comment: I am using the SDK version 3.21.1, I understand that the install will be only recorded once per device so I uninstalled and reinstalled the app several times, but neither that not app events are being registered. I dont have the FB app installed, and what do you mean by Andrdoid advertiser ID? I just intalled the SDK and set it up with the FB app ID from the app's settings in the developer site

Comment: https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/id.html You need either this enabled or the FB app installed in order to get install attribution.

Comment: @MingLi it looks you are correct, I installed the FB app and the install was registered! I would really appreciate it if you could post more details on how to integrate the Android Advertising ID, I searched but couldn't find any simple (that I could understand) instructions. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in my case the problem was adding the meta to the debug manifest