# Facebook Android SDK only working when native app installed

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-insights

I have created a game in Unity3D and installed the Facebook SDK for Unity.
I want to use the Facebook SDK for a very simple purpose, to track the app installs and the app launches, I do not require the Facebook Login or any other features.

When I published the game from Unity to iOS everything worked as expected, however, when publishing the game to Android, the events were not being registered by Facebook.

After posting this question [Facebook Android SDK not registering installs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27706095/facebook-android-sdk-not-registering-installs) @MingLi pointed out that either the Facebook Native app needs to be installed, and when I installed the native app the events started registering!

When the Native FB app is not installed I get this error:

```
Warning: Sessionless Request needs token but missing either application ID or client token
```

I have tried searching for a solution for that error, but nothing that I could find solves it without having the Native app installed.

How can I get the Facebook SDK to register events on Android when the Native app is not installed on the users device, like it works in iOS? Many thanks and TIA!

Comment: I am sorry for a bit off topic but I am curious, using facebook sdk for analytics seems a bit of an overkill. There are so many other alternatives for this purpose. What made you choose this?

Comment: Hey @hypd09 I agree with you, but this is a request of the customer, and unfortunately the customer is always right (even after explaining it to them)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, when you log an app event, you need to tell FB something about your app (otherwise the event will never get attributed to your app). If you don't have a Session, then you'll need either an app ID (at the very least), or a client token.

For app ID, you can either have it in your AndroidManifest.xml and strings.xml, or you can call Settings.setApplicationID() directly.

For client token, you can similarly call Settings.setClientToken().